# Calling recvfrom() and setsockopt() to add/leave multicast membership from different threads

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming, multicast

I have one thread calling recvfrom() and another thread calling setsockopt() to add/leave multicast membership. Is that thread safe or both functions need to be called from the same thread?

Comment: I don't know if it is thread-safe or not, but you could simply synchronize the two so the receiving thread does not call `recvfrom()` while the membership thread is calling `setsockopt()`, and vice versa. They don't have to be in the same thread, but you should probably avoid calling them concurrently.

Comment: @close-voter What exactly is unclear about this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are both system calls, not library functions, so it is safe to call them from different threads.

Whether a join/leave will affect a concurrent `recvfrom()` that has already started is a moot question.